# How to remove all the default Audacity effects?

Tags: windows-10, audacity

I just installed a fresh copy of Audacity and there are a few presets I want to turn off

- When I listen to playback, there's a few seconds at the beginning where the volume goes from quieter to louder. This happens each time I press record.
- There's some sort of ambiance filter that removes all the subtle background noise. I need to turn that off.

Ultimately, I just want to record without any special features turned on, is there a way to just turn all the "special" stuff off?

Answer (score 1):

In Audacity you may see the effects used via :

- Tools > Add/Remove Plug-ins...
- Effect > Add / Remove Plug-ins...
- Generate > Add / Remove Plug-ins...
- Analyze > Add / Remove Plug-ins...

By default all the Built-in effects, with the exception of Classic Filters, are loaded and enabled in Audacity.

To disable an effect, click it in the list in the dialog, then use either the Enable or Disable button and click the OK button. You may select more than one effect,
or all of them by the "Select All" button, and disable them all.

[image]

For more information see
[Add / Remove Effects, Generators and Analyzers](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/manage_effects_generators_and_analyzers.html).